# How to get the Data, Memory and Battery usage of installed application in android?

Tags: android

Explanation:
            I am trying to find the data, battery and memory usage of installed application in android. I have been tried a lot of things to get the data usage from API 22 to later. I used a TrafficStats to get data usage per application with the from and to time limit.

I got the data in negative format.

Here i have posted a code below:

```
public void getPakagesInfoUsingHashMap() {
        final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        // get a list of installed apps.
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);

        // loop through the list of installed packages and see if the selected
        // app is in the list
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            // get the UID for the selected app
            int UID = packageInfo.uid;
            String package_name = packageInfo.packageName;
            ApplicationInfo app = null;
            try {
                app = pm.getApplicationInfo(package_name, 0);
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String name = (String) pm.getApplicationLabel(app);
            Drawable icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(app);
            // internet usage for particular app(sent and received)
            double received = (double) TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(UID)

                    / (1024 * 1024);
            double send = (double) TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(UID)
                    / (1024 * 1024);
            double total = received + send;

            if(total>0)
            {

                Log.e(name,String.format( "%.2f", total )+" MB");
            }

        }
    }
```

Explanation of the code:It will print the installed application names along with the data usage of each application.

**Note: I have installed my application in API level 7.0(Nougat).**

I have read a lot of blog on the internet but i did't find the genuine solution for this particular problem.

Few blog suggested me to find NetworkStatManager. I don't get my data in MB of GB format from the NetworkStatManager.

Please help me solve out.

Comment: Thank you.Sir, Kindly if you know something about this issue please help me to solve out.

Comment: Can anyone help me to solve out this problem?